# How do I choose both exact quanitity wait for and quanitity available in the same pick-up block?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

So I have a vehicle which is going to pick up exact quantity (Wait for) the first 50 minutes in the simulation. After those 50 minutes have gone by, I want the same vehicle to pick up quantity (if available). How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative approach (avoiding complex Java coding) is to use 2 Pickup blocks, each with a different setup. Put a `SelectOutput` block before them and route agents into the respective block using `time()>50*minute()` in the `SelectOutput` condition

Answer (score 0):

Set it up for the first setup by default.

Create an event to trigger after 50 mins and make it execute this code:

```
myPickupObject.set_pickupType(PickupType.QUANTITY);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I am getting and error which is "The parameter type cannot be changed dynamically" when I do pickup2.set_pickupType(Pickup.QUANTITY); I tried with PickupType.QUANTITY but then it wouldnt run because PickupType could not be resolved to a variable

Comment: That is because you simply pasted the code. You must write it yourself using code-complete (Strl-space) so that the `PickupType` is imported as a Java class. Then, it will compile. Alternatively, paste `import com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Pickup.PickupType;` into the "Imports section" under "Advanced Java" in the properties of Main (or wherever the Pickup objects live)

Comment: I tried the alterntive and it still says "The parameter type cannot be changed dynamically" and also tried the solution above, but I the vechile have already entered the pick-up block way before when time was under 50 so its still stuck on the option to take exact. what to do? Thank you

Comment: It is possible that this cannot be changed at runtime. Use my other approach then

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to allow container entity to wait in a **Pickup** for some time *t* and then leave with whatever entities have been picked up. The example model looks like this:

[image]

There are two key components:

1. *ReleaseOnTimeout* Dynamic event which has a parameter called '_agent' of type Agent and following code:

```java
for (Object o : pickup.getEmbeddedObjects()) {
    // find the Delay object inside Pickup
    if (Delay.class == o.getClass().getSuperclass()) {
        // remove the container from the Delay
        Agent a = ((Delay)o).remove(_agent);
        if (a != null) {
            // send the removed container into Enter
            enter.take(a);
        }       
    }
}
```

2. In *pickup* `on enter` action contains following code: `create_ReleaseOnTimeout(10, container);

How this works:

1. *pickup* is configured to have `Exact quantity (wait for)` behaviour
2. a *container* object enters **Pickup** block *pickup*
3. on entry a dynamic event *ReleaseOnTimeout* is scheduled in 10 units to check up on *container*
4. if sufficient number of entities were available then *container* picks them up and leaves
5. alternatively to (4), if by the time 10 units elapsed the *container* is still stuck in *pickup* then it will be removed and put into *enter*